# Trouble connecting to mysql database when using a config file

Tags: php, mysql, database

I can't connect to my database when I use these files. Here they are with the php code.

The `db_config.php` file:

```
<?php
    define('DB_USER', "root");
    define('DB_PASSWORD', "mypassword");
    define('DB_DATABASE', "mydbname");
    define('DB_SERVER', "localhost");
?>
```

The `db_connect.php` file:

```
<?php

    class DB_CONNECT
    {
        //constructor
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->connect();
        }

        //destructor
        function __destruct()
        {
            $this.close();
        }

        function connect()
        {
            // import database connection variables
            require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

            $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
            $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());

            // returing connection cursor
            return $con;
        }

        function close()
        {
            //closing db connection
            mysql_close();
        }
    }

?>
```

The `add_team.php` file:

```
<?php

$response = array();

if(isset($_POST['team_full_name']) && isset($_POST['team_short_name']) && isset($_POST['league']))
{
    $team_fn = $_POST['team_full_name'];
    $team_sn = $_POST['team_short_name'];
    $league = $_POST['league'];

    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO teamData (team_full_name, team_short_name, league) VALUES ('$team_fn', '$team_sn', '$league')");

    if($result)
    {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Team Data successfully added.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Error occurred!";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    //for testing
    //mysql_close($dbhandle);
}
else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing.";
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

When I use these files to run the `add_team.php` file, my program crashes (using it in Java). But when I change the `add_team.php` file to not use the `DB_CONNECT` class like this:

```
<?php

$response = array();

if(isset($_POST['team_full_name']) && isset($_POST['team_short_name']) && isset($_POST['league']))
{
    $team_fn = $_POST['team_full_name'];
    $team_sn = $_POST['team_short_name'];
    $league = $_POST['league'];

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword") or die ("unable to connect to MySQL");
    $db = mysql_select_db("mydbname", $dbhandle);

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO teamData (team_full_name, team_short_name, league) VALUES ('$team_fn', '$team_sn', '$league')");

    if($result)
    {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Team Data successfully added.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Error occurred!";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    mysql_close($dbhandle);
}
else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing.";
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

it works perfectly. I was following a tutorial and the version that doesn't work is how the guy said to set it up. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to php so excuse me if you see statements that are deprecated, I will change them later. I'm using them because the tutorial I was following is pretty old and I don't know how to use the non-deprecated alternatives yet.

Also, I like this config file setup with the `DB_CONNECT` class, because I don't have to hard code my database password in the php files performing database transactions. It seems a bit safer than the version that works. So if I can get the better version working, is this a good setup? What if I want to make multiple inserts, updates, deletes, etc at one moment, am I going to have to reconnect and disconnect every single time I call one of my php files that performs a database transaction?

Comment: Is it normal that, in your `DB_CONNECT` class, you're using a `mysqli` object with `mysql_*` functions ?

Comment: @Aurel Oh forgot to change it to the original way I had. I was testing different things ha. But still it wasn't working. I'll change it back to the original way I had it to keep it more consistent.

Comment: Why you are mixing `oops` and `procedural` formats when there is no need to create a class is call that class? Why???

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I am completely new to php programming and server coding in general. I have been testing different things. I don't think you read my entire post because I acknowledged that my code may not be very good.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following in db_connect.php

```
<?php

class DB_CONNECT
{
    function connect()
    {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    function close()
    {
        //closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }
}

?>
```

And in your add_team.php update

```
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$dbCon = $db->connect();
$query = "INSERT INTO teamData (team_full_name, team_short_name, league) VALUES ('{$team_fn}', '{$team_sn}', '{$league}')";
$result = mysql_query($query,$dbCon);
```

Comment: Also you should consider using mysqli or PDO statement. as mysql is deprecated from latest versions of PHP. You can make use of ini file to store the details

Comment: I will do that. For now I'm not releasing my program to be used publicly. But when I do, I will definitely change the code to be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Dumb little bug that took me several hours to fix. In the destructor of the `DB_CONNECT` class I was calling `$this.close()` rather than `this->close()`. Completely fixed it.